# Foreign key constraints in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm using the ORM side of SQLAlchemy, and I've defined one of my columns to have a foreign key relation to another model, using:

```
Base = declarative_base()
class Model1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'm1'
    Name = Column(String, primary_key = True)
    info = Column(String)

class Model2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'm2'
    Name = Column(String, primary_key = True)
    info = Column(String)
    other_model = Column(String, ForeignKey('m1.Name'))
```

However, it doesn't seem to matter what I put in the `other_model` attribute, it seems more than happy to commit it to the database, even if there is no `Model1` instance that has that `Name`.

Comment: You may also have to define the relation using the `relation` factory.

Comment: @sayap using SQLite, @Keith thanks for the lead, I'll give it a go

Comment: Looks like it may be an issue with sqlite. I didn't realise but apparently sqlite doesn't support foreign key constraints... or at least didn't, [the newer bundles apparently do](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3296040/599251). I'll install a new version and see what happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the answer was in the database I was using (SQLite), not SQLAlchemy. SQLite versions <3.6.1 (AFAIK) do not support foreign key constraints.

The answer is therefore very similar to [this answer on foreign keys and SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2614984/599251).

As I'm using Windows, I was able to go to [the pysqlite2 page](http://code.google.com/p/pysqlite/), the packaged installers have version 3.7.6.2 sqlite, and then and the final implementation was aided by [this SQLAlchemy page on sqlite engines and dialects](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/dialects/sqlite.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.sqlite.pysqlite). This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3333095/599251) is also relevant with regards to the upgrade process.

Finally, the SQLite engine is a bit temperamental when deciding whether or not to enforce the foreign key constraint, and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2614984/599251) is quite useful in forcing the foreign key enforcement.