# How can I enforce SQLite foreign keys in python using pysqlite2?

Tags: python, sqlite, foreign-keys, enforcement

I have a SQLite database. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3296052/651779) you need version 3.6.19+, which I have. I made it using version 3.7.10 of SQLite:

```
>>> from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite
>>> print sqlite.sqlite_version
3.7.10
```

So it should support foreign keys.

I have the following sqlite database create statements:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `msrun`;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `msrun`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `msrun` (
  `msrun_name` VARCHAR(40) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
  `description` VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL );

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `feature`;
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `feature`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `feature` (
  `feature_id` VARCHAR(40) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL ,
  `intensity` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `overallquality` DOUBLE NOT NULL ,
  `charge` INT NOT NULL ,
  `content` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `msrun_msrun_name` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_feature_msrun1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`msrun_msrun_name` )
    REFERENCES `msrun` (`msrun_id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);

  CREATE UNIQUE INDEX `id_UNIQUE` ON `feature` (`feature_id` ASC);
  CREATE INDEX `fk_feature_msrun1` ON `feature` (`msrun_msrun_name` ASC);
```

So msrun_msrun_name in the feature table is a foreign key of msrun_name in the msrun table. However, when I'm filling up the feature table, I can fill in anything I want for msrun_msrun_name. The foreign key is not being enforced.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614984/sqlite-sqlalchemy-how-to-enforce-foreign-keys) the enforcing needs to be turned on, and it gives an answer how to do it with SQLAlchemy, but I'm not using SQLAlchemy.

How can I enforce foreign keys with pysqlite2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using SQLite's `PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;` command, it is disabled by default.

Comment: or in python cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON")

Answer (score 0):

Try to using the [PRAGMA](http://www.sqlite.org/foreignkeys.html) foreign_keys command. For example:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

then look if foreign keys are currently enabled:

```
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys;
0
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys;
1
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys = OFF;
sqlite> PRAGMA foreign_keys;
0
```